# GitHub Packages service authentication issue with nuget

Tags: nuget

So I started seeing this error when I was working with dotnet tools:

> /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.100/NuGet.targets(130,5): warning : Your request could not be authenticated by the GitHub Packages service. Please ensure your access token is valid and has the appropriate scopes configured.

The resources I saw on this were generally pointing to pipeline issues, but that wasn't the case for me.

Comment: The error says something about Github package source. That source is probably causing the issue. First list your packages using 'dotnet nuget list source'. Now yuo can try to temporarily disable that package source using 'dotnet nuget disable source @yourpackagesource' and re execute your command

Comment: just came back to this and realized that you just repeated what i had in my answer  well played

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Not sure what triggered this or why this resolves it for me, but if I disable and reenable my nuget source it works for me.

```sh
dotnet nuget list source
```

should return something like this:

```
Registered Sources:
  1.  nuget.org [Enabled]
      https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
```

then you want to disable and reenable it:

```sh
dotnet nuget disable source nuget.org
dotnet nuget enable source nuget.org
```